# How to convert UTC timezone to IST timezone while displaying in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

The date time object is stored in UTC in database and i want to convert to IST while displaying for my specific use case without changing the TIME_ZONE value in setting.py file.

I'm using django `defaultfilters.date(event['test'].start_time, 'DATETIME_FORMAT')` to format.

Comment: What is the TIME_ZONE value in your settings.py file?

Comment: @Shaumux its `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'`

I just need to convert to IST for my one specific datetime object not to the whole project wide setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the pytz library

```
from pytz import timezone
...
...
defaultfilters.date(event['test'].start_time.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Kolkata')), 'DATETIME_FORMAT')
```